# How to keep the military format when converting string to timestap in Oracle?

Tags: plsql

This is my code:

```
 l_ts := to_timestamp((d || ' 13:00:00'), 'DD.MM.YYYY:HH24:MI:SS'); 
 u_ts := to_timestamp((d || ' 17:00:00'), 'DD.MM.YYYY:HH24:MI:SS');
```

I keep getting:

```
26-MAY-13 01.00.00.000000 PM 26-MAY-13 05.00.00.000000 PM
```

I want:

```
26-MAY-13 13.00.00.000000 PM 26-MAY-13 17.00.00.000000 PM
```

i.e. **13** and **17** instead of **1** and **5**.

Thanks for hrlping

Comment: Change your NLS settings. A variable of type `timestamp` (or `date`) does ***not*** have any "format", it's only formatted by your SQL client (or your application) when you display it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you don't want 24-hour format as well as an am/pm indicator.

Comment: What is the type and value of the variable or field `d`?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are converting string to date, and then display the date directly. 
When You do it that way, the output is formatted to string internally and it depends on You session locale settings.

If You want to get the date in exactly the format You want, You should use [TO_CHAR](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php) function that will format Your date back to string when You need it to be displayed to User. With TO_CHAR You can use [format models](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00212) to get Your date in any format You wish (try to do it in SQL server... ;).

Consider this script:

```
set serveroutput on;
DECLARE 
    l_ts TIMESTAMP;
BEGIN
    -- Here You get DATE from STRING
    l_ts := to_timestamp(('01.01.2013' || ' 13:00:00'), 'DD.MM.YYYY:HH24:MI:SS'); 
    -- Here You get STRING representation of Your DATE. 
    -- Representation depends on You session settings, 
    -- and should not be relayed upon.
    dbms_output.put_line(l_ts);
    -- Examples how You can display DATE as STRING in any way You need
    dbms_output.put_line(TO_CHAR(l_ts,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));
    dbms_output.put_line(TO_CHAR(l_ts,'YYYY-MM-DD HH12:MI:SS AM'));
END;
```

Hope that will clear the issue. :)